# PHP PDO can't UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The same solution was working before but the parameters were not passed in JSON format and that's the only difference.

I even tried to write the SQL query manually with values not from variables and it's still giving back 0 rows affected.

What could cause this problem?

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=skistatus", "root", "");
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET") {
        $statement = $db->query('SELECT * FROM skilifts');
        $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($statement->fetchAll());
    }

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "PUT") {
        if($data['secret'] == "fee2c775c18a12b7b52b58129b00e1bd") {
            $sql = 'UPDATE skilifts SET `status` = :status WHERE `id` = :id';
            $query = $db->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute(array(":status"=>$data['status'], ":id"=>$data['id'] ));

            $count = $query->rowCount();
            if($count == '0'){
                echo "Failed";
                http_response_code(400);
            }
            else{
                echo "Success";
                http_response_code(200);
            }
        } else {
            echo $data['secret']." is not the magic word!";
            http_response_code(403);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: "still giving back 0 rows affected" - If the data didn't change, then MySQL will return "0 rows affected".

Comment: That's right but I'm getting zero rows affected even when I run this query: `UPDATE skilifts SET status=1 WHERE id=1`

Comment: Then either there is no row with `id=1` or the `status` in that row is already `1`. No changes => 0 rows affected.

Comment: And as I wrote above, the same code was working when I didn't passed the parameters in JSON format.

Comment: I've managed to fix it. :) Thanks @PaulSpiegel

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `id` wasn't being updated on the front-end before passing it to the back-end. Basically when the SQL query was executing, it was the same `id` with the same `status` value to be updated as the ones in the database, and therefore no rows were affected by the `UPDATE`